# How to create a docker image in WSL2 that requires installing linux-image and linux-headers

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-headers

I'm using docker inside WSL2 (Ubuntu), and trying to create a docker image. The image requires to install: `apt install -y linux-image-$(uname -r) linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.

I'm getting the following errors:

```
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
```

Comment: What happens when you try your command?

Comment: Why would you need to install a pre-compiled Linux kernel (`linux-image-$(uname -r)`) into the *virtual* environment of WSL2? The Windows kernel (not Linux kernel) controls all real hardware. Could this be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: `E: Unable to locate package linux-image-5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`
`E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.10.102.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2`

What I'm trying to do is create a docker image inside WSL2 which requires those.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add requested information or clarification. I suggest to write your basic question, e.g. "How to create a docker image in WSL2 (Ubuntu)?" and show what steps you are doing and where you are having problems.

Comment: You don't install a kernel on Docker containers.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I just noticed I still had this open in a tab I'd forgotten about.  There's probably a solution, but it may be necessary to know why you believe your image needs the headers in the first place.  What type of image are/were you trying to create?

Comment: Nope, moved on. I was checking steps for host os, and trying to replicate it on docker.